# Dojo chart custom tooltips

Tags: dojo

I include

```
"dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip" ...

... function(ready, Chart, Spider, Tooltip, Base){
```

I have the tooltip set up, if I do something basic like return('test'), that shows properly.

```
var tip = new Tooltip(chart, "default",
            {
                text : function(o) {

                }
            });
```

I add my series like so:

```
chart.addSeries("min", {data: data[0] }, { fill: "blue" });
chart.addSeries("max", {data: data[1] }, { fill: "blue" });
chart.addSeries("Answered", {data: data[2] }, { fill: "#37B549" });
```

How do I access the charts data?

Right now tooltips by default show:

```
Question 1 //series
test1
10 //Axis point
```

I only want tooltips to say [10 out of [max]]

I tried using o.tdata.data to get the point(10), but that threw a lot of errors.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your custom tooltip in your series dataset. Like:

```
mychart.addSeries("line_series", 
               [{y:1,x:1,tooltip: "bar 1"}, 
                {y: 3,x:2,tooltip: "bar 2"}, 
                {y:5,x:3,tooltip: "bar 3"}], 
                {plot: "line_plot"});
```

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/goinoff/5VYhN/2/